# document.referrer not working in safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, referrer

I am using document.referrer to get referrer url in javascript.

It is working fine in Mozilla, Chrome and IE but not working in SAFARI. Why ?

Comment: Please provide some code samples. The question is hard to answer in its current format.

Comment: Simple, here is the code
<script type="text/javascript">
   var backURL = document.referrer;
</script>

Comment: By the way, it seems to work fine here > http://jsfiddle.net/gsb2E/

Comment: OK, what are you actually doing with the variable?

Comment: Actully i have search results. when i open any result to new tab then new tab will not have back history in browser. so i am using document.referrer value for write cookie. and then create link for back. got it ?

Comment: Yes. As I said, please show **all** of the relevant code. As indicated, `document.referrer` does work in Safari. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Same code working in all browser. only issue with safari.

Comment: Hello BenM, I think you are right. It is working in safari but only referr Domain name not with query string. i mean in other browser it gives me result like this which i wants

  http://www.test.com/test/1/2/3

And safari gives me result like this 

    http://www.test.com

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please see the jsFiddle demo I posted. Safari correctly reports the referrer as `http://jsfiddle.net/gsb2E/`.

Comment: @BenM it seems you were wrong here. 
This is definitely an issue- I am seeing the same on Safari. It only returns the hostname.

Comment: @Neel did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Safari prevents cross-site tracking. Chrome is doing the same since a couple of versions.

For "compliant" browsers, you can use the Referrer-Policy tag:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

At least for me, it fixes chrome but not Safari issues. You need to change that setting in the settings menu for the browser.